# Android: Check alpha state in if

Tags: android

So i have a `OnClickListner`, in here i would like to check the alpha state of a vector img.

```
p1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (/*aplpa*/ == 1) {           //<----- alpha here
            if (array[0] == 'o') {
                p1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_red);
                array[0] = 'x';
            } else {
                p1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_green);
                array[0] = 'o';
            }
            array[1] = 1;
            p1.setAlpha(1);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you clarify more as to what the problem is? I cannot understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I wanted to check the transparency state in a IF and didn't know how. I have now made a new array and i'm checking that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't make your logic depend on the visible state of the app.  Instead you should have some variable in your app which is what you set the alpha to when needed, and which you can check when you want.